# execl error == "file exists" when the file doesn't exist

Tags: c, execl

I'm trying to understand the error returned by execl when it is trying to launch a file that doesn't exist.

Here is my code for this experiment, where main calls the function spawn1 that will create the fork and try to launch execl:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <assert.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int spawn1(char *, char *, char *);

int main(){
  int i, t, tt, state;

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    t = spawn1("functiondoesntexist", "strange name", "argument");
    if (t < 0){
      perror("fork"); // fork error
      break;
    }
    tt = wait(&state);
    assert(tt == t);
    if (state != 0){
      perror("exec didn't work");
      break;
    }
  }
  return i != 10;
}

int spawn1(char * file, char * command, char * arg){
  int t;

  t = fork();
  if (t < 0)                    // fork error
    return -1;

  if (t == 0){                  // child
    execl(file, command, arg, (void *)0);
    exit(1); 

  }
                                // parent
  return t;
}
```

the error returned is:

```
exec didn't work: File exists
```

Why isn't it more something like "File DOESN'T exist"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling `perror` in the correct places.

When a function fails, you need to check `errno` or call `perror` **immediately** after the function that failed.  Any other system or library function that is called after the one that failed will overwrite `errno` with its own error code.

Change you code to call `perror` right away as follows:

```
int main(){
  int i, t, tt, state;

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    t = spawn1("functiondoesntexist", "strange name", "argument");
    if (t < 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");   // not perror
      break;
    }
    tt = wait(&state);
    assert(tt == t);
    if (state != 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "exec didn't work\n");    // not perror
      break;
    }
  }
  return i != 10;
}

int spawn1(char * file, char * command, char * arg){
  int t;

  t = fork();
  if (t < 0) {                   // fork error
    perror("fork failed");      // call perror here to check fork
    return -1;
  }

  if (t == 0){                  // child
    execl(file, command, arg, (void *)0);
    perror("exec failed");      // call perror here to check execl
    exit(1); 

  }
                                // parent
  return t;
}
```